# How to control syntax prettify in a quote block?

Tags: support, syntax-highlighting

I [recently answered a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6327405/send-get-https-request-but-get-403-forbidden-response-why-why/6327493#6327493) quoting heavily from an RFC. Since the RFCs only look tolerable with code formatting, I tried to mark it up with both code indenting and quoting. But the RFC rendered with syntax highlighting / code prettyifier looked hilariously bad. So I tried to turn it off with the following two attempts, neither one worked. Both colored the RFC text.

`<!-- language: lang-none -->` hint on a line by itself:

```
<!-- language: lang-none -->

>     The absoluteURI form is REQUIRED when the request is being made to a
>     proxy. The proxy is requested to forward the request or service it
```

`> <!-- language: lang-none -->` hint, and the blank line required for the formatting hint to function (annoying, btw) represented with `>` as well:

```
> <!-- language: lang-none -->
> 
>     The absoluteURI form is REQUIRED when the request is being made to a
>     proxy. The proxy is requested to forward the request or service it
```

In a true comedic stroke, I can't reproduce the problem here, on [meta], and my edit was quick enough on my original answer that the problematic input *there* has been thrown away. (Which is overall a *wonderful* feature, thanks.)

What is the correct way to insert `<!-- language: lang-foo -->` tags into code-formatted quoted content?

Comment: For quoting plain text in preformatted code I use the good ol' `<pre></pre>` tags. Just as they were meant to be used. Not that that would relate to your question of course :)

Comment: @Bolt, that probably would have worked just as well as the four-space code formatting I used in the end. I mean, the difference between quoted code and code is _so_ slim that it is nearly pointless. (But the CSS might change in the future to have a larger distinction.) Or I might want a _different_ language, not just `lang-none`.

Answer (score 3):

Seems to work with the bigger hammer `<!-- language-all: lang-foo -->`:

---

```c
void foo(int);
```

> ```
> void foo(int);
> ```

> ```c
> void foo(int);
> ```

```
void foo(int);
```

---

```
<!-- language-all: lang-c -->

    void foo(int);

<!-- language-all: lang-none -->

>     void foo(int);

<!-- language-all: lang-c -->

>     void foo(int);

<!-- language-all: lang-none -->

    void foo(int);
```

---

> ```
> void foo(char);
> ```
>
> ```c
> void bar(long);
> ```

---

This workaround appears to work on Stack Overflow too (on that specific post).

<sub>Seriously not pretty here though.</sub>

Comment: I have tried to attempt it with [this question](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/51429/chain-of-responsibility-pattern).  I try to apply *lang:none* with the quote at the bottom, but it only works if I remove the quotes.

Comment: It works with `language-all:`, not with `language:`.

Comment: I have applied that to the question, and it appears to work!

Comment: Cool. The margin at the bottom of the quote block is a bit too thick IMO (compared to the margin on top), but I don't think that's fixable from markdown.