# How can I prevent syntax higlighting in markdown?

Tags: support, markdown, syntax-highlighting

When I wished to show example data, I used the code block syntax (4 spaces indentation after an empty line), but the data was rendered like a programming language. Can I prevent the syntax highlighting?

```
2013-01-01 1.30 1.35 1236
2013-01-02 1.20 1.37 1237
```

...or is there another syntax in markdown?

---

EDIT:

I the above example, the problem seems not to occur? The original problem, and data

```
James Bond
01/01/12 200010
03/30/12 -40000
04/30/12 -40000
05/30/12 -40000
06/30/12 -40000
07/30/12 -40000
```

was here: [C++ Bank Project; How do I read string from file convert to float and sum all](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19676589/2932052)

Comment: @hims056: this questions deals with forcing highlighting and doing it right

Comment: @Quantas 94 Heavy: As I already mentioned, this is a very vague question with no formal answer.

Comment: @WolfP. - The first language code given there is *"none"*

Comment: @hims056: Yes. But it's 5 questions and the 3rd of them matches only partially. Also, I'm still undecided which solution is better in the case of non-code: [code blocks](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax#precode]) or the pre tag which is [basic markdown](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax#html) (in the latter case the text would be "portable")...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use the `lang-none` [syntax highlighting comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help#syntax-highlighting):

```
<!-- language: lang-none -->

    Your data...
```

Comment: This seemed the first choice to me, but for plain text I considered it as an "overkill". BTW: is there a sandbox for testing safely?

Comment: @Wolf, yes, [there is](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/formatting-sandbox).

Comment: @WolfP. [There's a formatting sandbox on Meta](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/formatting-sandbox), but if that doesn't cut it you'll just have to abuse the live preview on SO.

Comment: @michaelb958: Thanks. I saw only now that syntax highlighting is also active in the preview, but delayed. Knowing that, I feel much better :)

Comment: @WolfP. Yeah, you have to stop typing for five (5) seconds before syntax highlighting happens in the preview.

Answer (score 5):

Just use `<pre>` tags:

```
<pre>
2013-01-01 1.30 1.35 1236
2013-01-02 1.20 1.37 1237
</pre>
```

It will display the text *as is*:

```
2013-01-01 1.30 1.35 1236
2013-01-02 1.20 1.37 1237
```

Here on meta there's no code prettify so it's not relevant.

Comment: Thanks :) I found this as a comment to this post http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/94902/238205 but the question was not clear and the answer missing.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the block quote, which is the character `>` then your text, like this:

> 2013-01-01 1.30 1.35 1236
>   2013-01-02 1.20 1.37 1237

The reason why your data was colour coded was due to the language you tagged your question with.

**Edit:** Disregard this - it's an option but Frédéric's is better and Shadow's example means a more appropriate font is used.

Comment: In tried this, but it did not what I wanted.